# POSTGRESQL converting column to JSON and taking care of the old data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column which is of *integer* type and I wanted to alter my column and convert it to *json* type while also taking care of the old data present.

So let's say I have this old data: *99* 
And I want to convert it to : *{ id: 99 }*

I'm trying this alter statement:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ALTER COLUMN "idColumn" TYPE json
USING CONCAT('{id:', "idColumn", '}')::json;
```

But I'm having an error regarding the invalid column token.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of your problem is, that the key `id`  needs to be enclosed in double quotes to be valid json, e.g. `concat('{"id":', "idColumn", '}')`.

Creating valid JSON values, is easier done using `json_build_object`

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
  ALTER COLUMN "idColumn" TYPE json
  USING json_build_object('id', "idColumn");
```

But `jsonb` is recommended over `json`, so ideally it would be:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
  ALTER COLUMN "idColumn" TYPE jsonb
  USING jsonb_build_object('id', "idColumn");
```

---

You should also avoid quoted identifiers, they are much more trouble in the long run, than they are worth it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with quotation marks in your query. Check this out, it works:

```
drop table if exists mytable;
create table mytable (id integer, idColumn integer, name varchar(100));
insert into mytable values (1, 99, 'jasiek');
ALTER TABLE mytable
ALTER COLUMN idColumn TYPE json
USING CONCAT('{"id":', idColumn, '}')::json;
SELECT idColumn::TEXT FROM mytable;
```